# How can I move picture box out of panel?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have picture box in panel and i want to move this picture box with my mouse.
This script works good but I can only move it inside this panel. What should I do to move it to form or other panel?

```
    Point firstPoint = new Point();

    public void MoveImage()
    {
        pictureBox1.MouseDown += (ss, ee) =>
        {
            if (ee.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                firstPoint = Control.MousePosition;
            }
        };
        pictureBox1.MouseMove += (ss, ee) =>
        {
            if (ee.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                Point temp = Control.MousePosition;
                Point res = new Point(firstPoint.X - temp.X, firstPoint.Y - temp.Y);
                pictureBox1.Location = new Point(pictureBox1.Location.X - res.X, pictureBox1.Location.Y - res.Y);
                firstPoint = temp;
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sample code that will bring out the control from the container,please modify it as required or add it to your code :

```
    int i = 0;

    void moveout()

    {          
        if (i % 2 == 0)

        {

            // if the control is in a container control

            if (picturebox.Parent.Name!= this.Name)

            {          

                Point moveLocation = new Point(picturebox.Location.X + picturebox.Parent.Location.X,                                                              picturebox.Location.Y + picturebox.Parent.Location.Y);

                // remove the control first

                picturebox.Parent.Controls.Remove(picturebox);

                this.Controls.Add(picturebox);

                picturebox.Location = moveLocation;

            }       
            picturebox.SendToBack();
        }
        else
        {
            picturebox.BringToFront();
        }
    ++i;
    }
```

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/0afe6404-9c91-41c7-92af-6a47b379f6e0/move-controls-from-one-tablelayoutpanel-to-another-panel?forum=winformsapplications)

Hope this works..If it doesn't , leave a comment before downvoting :)

Comment: picturebox disapear when I hit Start

Comment: when u click start ?? what is start ?

Comment: are u using `picturebox.BringToFront()` ??

Comment: it's ok now, I modified your code a little bit and now it works fine :) Thank you for help :)